# Why isn't Spring chaining ExceptionHandlers?

Tags: java, spring, exception

I have several Spring `@ExceptionHandlers` as follows:

```
@ExceptionHandler(MailerException.class)
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
public String mailerException(MailerException e, HttpServletRequest request, Locale locale) {
    FlashMap outputFlashMap = RequestContextUtils.getOutputFlashMap(request);
    if (outputFlashMap != null) {
        outputFlashMap.put("flashMessage", messageSource.getMessage("controller.internal_server_error", null, locale));
    }
    return "redirect:/index";
}

@ExceptionHandler(ExecutionException.class)
public String executionException(ExecutionException e) throws Throwable {
    throw e.getCause();
}
```

When an `ExecutionException` is thrown with a `MailerException` as the cause, the `executionException` handler is invoked but not the `mailerException` one...

I am not sure why... Can anyone please explain?

Here is the **stacktrace**:

```
GRAVE: Servlet.service() for servlet [bignibou] in context with path [/bignibou] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.bignibou.MailerException: MessagingException | MailSendException] with root cause
com.bignibou.MailerException: MessagingException | MailSendException
    at com.bignibou.service.preference.PreferenceServiceImpl.sendPasswordResetInfo_aroundBody10(PreferenceServiceImpl.java:122)
    at com.bignibou.service.preference.PreferenceServiceImpl$AjcClosure11.run(PreferenceServiceImpl.java:1)
    at org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.AbstractTransactionAspect.ajc$around$org_springframework_transaction_aspectj_AbstractTransactionAspect$1$2a73e96cproceed(AbstractTransactionAspect.aj:59)
    at org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.AbstractTransactionAspect$AbstractTransactionAspect$1.proceedWithInvocation(AbstractTransactionAspect.aj:65)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262)
    at org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.AbstractTransactionAspect.ajc$around$org_springframework_transaction_aspectj_AbstractTransactionAspect$1$2a73e96c(AbstractTransactionAspect.aj:63)
    at com.bignibou.service.preference.PreferenceServiceImpl.sendPasswordResetInfo_aroundBody12(PreferenceServiceImpl.java:111)
    at com.bignibou.service.preference.PreferenceServiceImpl$AjcClosure13.run(PreferenceServiceImpl.java:1)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.aspectj.AbstractAsyncExecutionAspect.ajc$around$org_springframework_scheduling_aspectj_AbstractAsyncExecutionAspect$1$6c004c3eproceed(AbstractAsyncExecutionAspect.aj:58)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.aspectj.AbstractAsyncExecutionAspect.ajc$around$org_springframework_scheduling_aspectj_AbstractAsyncExecutionAspect$1$6c004c3e(AbstractAsyncExecutionAspect.aj:62)
    at com.bignibou.service.preference.PreferenceServiceImpl.sendPasswordResetInfo(PreferenceServiceImpl.java:111)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncExecutionInterceptor$1.call(AsyncExecutionInterceptor.java:128)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Here is what gets displayed in the browser:

```
Etat HTTP 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.bignibou.MailerException: MessagingException | MailSendException
```

Comment: The annotated exception handling only applies to controller methods as part of the request processing.  After you handle an error you're outside of that into a more utilitarian layer.  I'd have to do research into how it actually hangs together, but the why is because an exception thrown means something went wrong so you don't want to expect things like the framework to help you much: otherwise you could end up in trouble with things like not being able to get your errors or the dreaded cascading of errors.

Comment: In your previous question, I meant that you should catch the `ExecutionException` in your controller and re-throw its `cause` there.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: uhmmm... I could catch the ExecutionException in the controller method but it would further complexify my controllers. I do rethrow the cause though. Any idea why the first handler (i.e. `@ExceptionHandler(MailerException.class)`) is not called?

Comment: It's as @Matt explains.

Comment: @MattWhipple: I see. Then I guess something is wrong with my use of Spring Mvc. Any idea how to achieve what I want to achieve - short of rethrowing the cause in every of my controller methods?

Comment: It seems like you're trying to use the exception handling as an additional dispatcher mechanism rather than..well..exception handling.    You could create your own basic dispatching mechanism if desired.  At a glance it just looks like you're overcomplicating things though...why are you re-throwing the wrapped exception just to unwrap it?  If you can avoid that then you can just let the standard exception selection work.  There are also a lot of blog posts out there about the different ways to use Spring exception handling to do a lot for you, but you still need to keep the right perspective.

Comment: If you're looking to bypass checked exceptions (certainly understandable), then you should be throwing different RuntimeExceptions for the different exceptions that you want to handle. The exception hierarchy that you're using would then also correspond to the expected control flow more cleanly.  If you want to leverage the type system for dispatching then do the mapping, if you want to roll your own then don't try to use what Spring offers for more than an entry point.

Comment: Thanks all for your input. Matt: I understand your point about dispatching vs exception handling.

Comment: Sorry for the comment storm, I didn't know it was coming.  A large factor in the decision above should also be how much your _logic_ changes between errors.  If the flow is different there should be different methods (& different exceptions).  If the flow is the same with different arguments, then using the single wrapper exception may make more sense (or single entry point either way) and then having a system built to retrieve the arguments for the wrapped exception. I recently did the latter for a REST interface to map an exception tree to `ResponeEntitiy`s (only caught the parent).